# In React how to make radio button checked if the value matching with json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The form has radio buttons which generate question from `answers:[{}]` it save based on`onChage` to the `answers:[{}]` as selected.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/mm4qrv4o6j

Current status of the questions and answers are

```
const question = {
  questions: {
    questionID: 1,
    title: "Your gender ?",
    values: [{ id: "1", value: "Male" }, { id: "2", value: "Female" }]
  }
};

this.state = {
  answers: [
    {
      questionID: "1",
      answerValues: "2"
    }
  ]
};
```

Unfortunately not able to update the answer because the radio onChange doesn't allow to change

```
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
  {options.map(option => {
    return (
      <div className="form-check" key={option.id}>
        <label className="radio-inline" htmlFor={`${name}-${option.id}`}>
          <input
            name={name}
            id={`${name}-${option.id}`}
            data-question-id={questionID}
            type="radio"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={option.id}
            checked={option.id == checked.questionID}
          />{" "}
          {option.value}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: And then there is this: https://uxdesign.cc/designing-forms-for-gender-diversity-and-inclusion-d8194cf1f51

Comment: You could use the state and update it's reference when a selection is made https://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/WGJgAx?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note this structure doesn't seem suitable for when you add more questions/answers (an array is probably more suitable):

```
answered: {
  answers: {
    questionID: "1",
    answerValues: "1"
  }
}
```

The first and main issues is that your root component that controls when the sub ones are going to re-render, is never re-rendered itself. To solve this you can use local state to update answers:

```
const question = {
  questions: {
    questionID: 1,
    title: "Your gender ?",
    values: [{ id: "1", value: "Male" }, { id: "2", value: "Female" }]
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    answered: {
      answers: {
        questionID: "1",
        answerValues: "1"
      }
    },
  }
  updateAnswer = (newAnswer) => {
    this.setState({
      answered: {
        answers: newAnswer,
      },
    });
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div style={styles}>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {"\u2728"}</h2>
        <hr />
        <FormQuestion question={question.questions} answered={this.state.answered.answers} updateAnswer={this.updateAnswer}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

The final issue is that the checked ID is in a confusingly named "answerValues", not "questionID", so change to:

```
checked={option.id === checked.answerValues}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/62ovz1kql3

Comment: Just updated the question with `onChange` update `answers:[]`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refactor your solution and put inputs inside the `form` tag. Then simply remove `onChange` from the Radio and add it to the `form`. Then just run your code again.

Comment: Could please explain ?

Comment: HTML form tag has `onChange` method, which is triggered once any of the fields inside form gets changed. If you put radio-input inside `<form></form>` and add `onChange` to the form instead of the radio - it will trigger whenever radio is changed.